# Aligning text with bootstrap pull-right

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display an image and under the image have the time to the left and a count of the comments to the right on the same line. Unfortunately my comment count is appearing to the top right of the image.

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <div class="well well-sm">
    <%= image_tag(article.attachments.first.attachment_url, class: "picture") %>
    <span class="flag pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment")></i> <span class="badge">5</span></span>
    <h6>
      Posted by: Administrator
      <%= time_ago_in_words(article.created_at) %> ago.
    </h6>
    <p class="lead"><%= article.title %></p>          
    <%= simple_format(article.content[0,300]) %>
    <%= link_to "More", article_path(@article) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: wrap the `img` tag in `div`

Comment: Worked thanks. Is this because the <div></div> acts as a separator when using pull-right?

Comment: `IMG` elements are inline, meaning that unless they are floated they will flow horizontally with text and other inline elements. whereas `DIV` is a block-level element: A block-level element always starts on a new line and takes up the full width available.

Comment: Please post this answer and I will accept it. It is simple and concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap the `img` tag in `div`

HTML:

```
<div>
 <%= image_tag(article.attachments.first.attachment_url, class: "picture") %>
</div>
```

> IMG elements are inline, meaning that unless they are floated they
>   will flow horizontally with text and other inline elements. whereas
>   DIV is a block-level element: A block-level element always starts on a
>   new line and takes up the full width available.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below approach for getting the same.

I posted an example for the same. you can use `pull-right` class in span tag.

Here is `pull-right` and `pull-left` class fiddle example.

**[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/v8o3j7wf/17/)**

```css
.wrapper {
    max-width: 230px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 5px;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.image + .text {
    margin-top: 4px;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}

.text span:nth-of-type(1) {
    float: left;
}

.text span:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="image">
 <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/" alt="">
 </div>
 <div class="text">
 <span>time</span><span>comment</span>
 </div>
</div>
```